# Client ID or Multiple Audiences In JSON Web Token

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt, json-web-token

I am implementing OAuth 2.0 with JWT in my application and am having trouble deciding what to set as my `aud` claim as. A user will "login" to my client via my authentication server to gain access to my API (resource) server. I want my tokens to only be valid for use with a specific client and specific API.

[image: authentication flow]

When logging in from my client, I include it't `client_id` in the request, but in [most](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/concepts/understanding-jwt.html#token-structure-claims) [implementations](https://auth0.com/docs/jwt) [I've](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token) [found](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-token-and-claims/#token-claims-reference), the `aud` is set to that `client_id`. I'm leaning towards including a customer `audience_id` field in my login request and then setting the `aud` in the token to an array of the `client_id` and the `audience_id`, but that *feels* like it just means that that token is valid for both those `audiences`, which makes me think I should just add a custom claim called `client` to specifically state that this token was created for a specific client.

I have not come across any implementations online that include both a `client_id` and `audience_id`(s) in an OAuth login request, nor do I see a reserved claim for `client` [in the spec](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html#rfc.section.4.1.3).

Am I missing something here?

**What is best practice for specifically stating a different `client_id` and `audience_id` in a JWT?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The audience of the JWT is the Resource Server as that is where the token will be processed, i.e. verified, inspected and acted upon. From RFC 7519, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.3:

> The "aud" (audience) claim identifies the recipients that the JWT is
> intended for.  Each principal intended to process the JWT MUST
> identify itself with a value in the audience claim.
> [...]
> The interpretation of audience values is generally application specific.
> [...]

So best practice is that `aud` should identify the Resource Server.

The Client is only the presenter of the token and it is best practice (i.e. in OpenID Connect and some emerging OAuth 2.0 exension drafts) to use the `azp` (Authorized Presenter) for that claim. From http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeIDToken :

> `azp`
> OPTIONAL. Authorized party - the party to which the ID Token was
> issued. If present, it MUST contain the OAuth 2.0 Client ID of this
> party. This Claim is only needed when the ID Token has a single
> audience value and that audience is different than the authorized
> party.
> [...]

So best practice is that `azp` identifies the Client.

Comment: and then include an `audience_id` in the initial login request from the client indicating what audience they are requesting access to?

Comment: that relationship can indirectly be created using the `scope` concept (and request parameter); this allows for more flexibility than just a one-to-one mapping between scope and resource server; in general a scope models an access permission: a scope may map to a resource server but may also map to a particular resource protected by a resource server among others, or a collection of resource servers